# Strange Error with Devel::DProf

Tags: perl, profile

I want to profile my Perl code by using `Devel::DProf`.

when I am running the profiler like

`perl5.8 -d:DProf abc.pl`  # default version of Perl in my PC (Solaris) is 5.003

then it produces the `tmon.out` file in the current directory, but when I run

```
dprofpp
```

then it is not undertanding the command and giving error like **command not found**.

I know [Devel::DProf](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/Devel-DProf-20110802.00/DProf.pm) - a DEPRECATED Perl code profiler, and should use [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-4.06/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm) but just want to know why it is giving such an error, may be I am missing something.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out where you installed `dprofpp` and ensure that the directory is in your PATH, or call it with the full path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.when I find out where dprofpp installed by using `perldoc -l dprofpp` then I got the path `/usr/local/perl/5.8.0/bin/dprofpp`, then I call it with full path in the current directory, and able to get the report.Thanks a lot.